# How does streaming stream 30 480x640 images over a 2mbit/s line

Tags: image-processing, video-streaming

I'm having a strange realization while working on a project I'm having.

I created a streaming solution where i stream  a image with the resolution 480x640 totaling at 30’720 pixels, and every pixel contains 32bits of data and by my calculations this means that every frame totals to 1,2MB of data which means that 30fps would total to a 36MB/s line.

So to my question how does a streaming solution stream 30fps over f.ex 2mbit/s line?

I'm guessing that the same question can probably used to explain how a jpg image with a  480x640 resolution takes up <100KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression is your friend.

I don't know the specifics of your solution, but a few assumptions can be made.

First off, even if you send each frame as a full frame, they should be compressed.  Even lossless compression should get you some pretty good compression rates, but if you go with something lossy (like jpg) then you can get even more.

But that's not all you get.  Any good video codec should provide significant compression as well.  Parts of the image that don't change between frames don't need to be sent at all, and other parts can be compressed nicely too (I don't know much specifics about the compression used, but there's a lot of stuff that's done to compress it).

This all adds up to a lot of savings over sending a full 32bit bitmap for every frame.

Comment: but how does one compress an image? as i see it you would have to have at least 24bit per pixel just to display the picture in full coloring. So from my point of view 24bit is the bare minimum. but then logic crashes with reality and i understand my logic is flawed. I know I'm a noob and this is my first attempt in this area. i cannot use a regular compression as the pictures are sent from a win phone and i would like to do it from scratch just to learn some techniques now ignoring unchanged pixels that i implemented on my own and it gave bout 5-15% boost btw :D

Comment: Compression lets you store the same data in a smaller space. It generally takes advantage of repeated data. And many compression algorithms are fast enough to run in realtime.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression

Answer (score 0):

Compression is a very broad topic. Just to get an idea, try reading the wikipedia page about [image compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression)

As a very basic solution to your problem, I would personally jpeg-encode the first frame, then, jpeg-encode the differences between two consecutive frames.

For jpeg compression there are many libraries providing the functionality, without the need to implement it yourself.

If you are not so interested in the quality, you can also subsample the video, for example obtaining frames of resolution 240*320

Comment: And compressions are done at almost no cost to time? is it possible to do it 30 times a second?

Comment: Can't really answer o this, it depends on too many factors. I guess the easiest thing to do is just trying :)